# The 0.3 WebJobs SDK broke my parameter bindings

Tags: azure-storage, azure-webjobs

I have the following method definition:

```
public static void ProcessPackageRequestMessage(
    [QueueTrigger(queues.PACKAGE)] PackageRequestMessage message, 
    [Blob(blobs.PACKAGE + "/{RequestId}_{BlobFile}")] ICloudBlob blob,
    [Table(tables.PACKAGE)] CloudTable table,
    [Queue(queues.EMAIL)] out PackageEmailMessage packageEmailMessage)
```

The class PackageRequestMessage is defined as follows:

```
public class PackageRequestMessage
{
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }
    public Guid FactoryId { get; set; }
    public string BlobFile { get; set; }
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

In version 0.2 of the SDK, when a JSON message of PackageRequestMessage was posted to the queue, this method was called, and the appropriate Blob was found, based on the parameters in the PackageRequestMessage (RequestId, and BlobFile), and all worked well.

Now, in version 0.3 of the SDK, I get the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: Exception binding parameter 'blob' ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No value for name parameter 'RequestId'
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.RouteParser.ApplyNamesWorker(String pattern, IDictionary`2 names, Boolean allowUnbound)
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.RouteParser.ApplyBindingData(String pattern, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 bindingData)
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Host.Blobs.Bindings.BlobBinding.Bind(BindingContext context)
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Host.Runners.TriggerParametersProvider`1.Bind()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Host.Runners.DelayedException.Throw()
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Host.Runners.WebSitesExecuteFunction.ExecuteWithSelfWatch(MethodInfo method, ParameterInfo[] parameterInfos, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters, TextWriter consoleOutput)
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Host.Runners.WebSitesExecuteFunction.ExecuteWithOutputLogs(FunctionInvokeRequest request, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameters, TextWriter consoleOutput, CloudBlobDescriptor parameterLogger, IDictionary`2 parameterLogCollector)
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Host.Runners.WebSitesExecuteFunction.ExecuteWithLogMessage(FunctionInvokeRequest request, RuntimeBindingProviderContext context, FunctionStartedMessage message, IDictionary`2 parameterLogCollector)
 at Microsoft.Azure.Jobs.Host.Runners.WebSitesExecuteFunction.Execute(FunctionInvokeRequest request, RuntimeBindingProviderContext context)

In the dashboard, the message itself is shown with a valid RequestId present in the JSON, so I'm not sure why it's reported missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pianomanjh, I was able to reproduce the issue you are describing and I filed a bug. It seems that this failure only occurs in the blob name pattern, parameter binding is not affected.

The workaround for now is to use `string` instead of `Guid` for the property types.

Comment: thank you, looking forward to getting proper Guid parsing back.

Answer (score 0):

Just found a solution to the blob issue i 0.3.0. Compared to version 0.2.0 you have to define the Blob to FileAccess.Write to make it work. It fixed the issue I described above to be able to stream to a blob